How can Joe Biden be removed as candidate for the election?

Just an hour into Thursday night’s presidential debate, Andrew Yang — a 2020 Democratic presidential candidate — called on Biden to step aside.
“Guys, the Dems should nominate someone else — before it’s too late. #swapJoeout,” Yang wrote on X.

Source: WaPo
Can Joe Biden be removed as the Democratic candidate for President and how would this be done?

The question would probably be much better if generalized a bit. Like how could a major US party decide on a different candidate once the primaries are over. Or something else. It doesn't really depend on the specific candidate.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I doubt popularity is why.  IMO it's more likely because it's really hard to win a party's nomination over an incumbent first-term President who decides to run for reelection. (Has it ever been done?) The reason there's no potential candidate who's popular right now is because no one spent the time, effort, and money to make themselves popular enough to run. Because they didn't see any way to beat Biden - before last night, anyway.

@JustMe But there were Democratic party primaries taking place and there is no rule a single president must do two terms. Not taking part in a democratic contest risks that suboptimal candidates get the job. Even the Republican primaries were contested more . But yeah, I fully agree with your logic. That's probably what many Democratic potential candidates thought, it's either Biden or Trump and they were kind of fine with this match.

@RickSmith I don't think there's really a duplicate possible for the current situation with Biden.  The questions raised by Biden's performance last night did not exist 8 years ago and Biden's performance last night clearly has created a push for replacing him.  IMO this makes for a unique situation well-deserving of a specific question.

@JustMe But we shouldn't speculate or try to predict the future here. We can only answer what is possible and that should not really depend on the specific person. The law/mechanisms should be the same 8 years ago and now. If anything the duplicate is too narrow. Maybe there is something else that can be done. For example the candidate chooses a running mate that is the real candidate and promises to go on day one. Might also work (theoretically) without ignoring the primaries.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I think this situation is different as there is a lot more going on than just replacing a party's candidate.  Biden is the incumbent President, which adds significant complexity that is missing in the proposed duplicate and IMO clearly changes things.

@JustMe Formally it doesn't change anything for the election in which all candidates are equal. And I bet that all given answers will not depend on the candidate being the incumbent. But I also don't think it's a duplicate. It can use a lot more context though.

@JustMe Biden being a sitting President changes nothing about the nomination and voting process. There are several duplicates that apply here.

@Machavity I don't see any other question where the 25th Amendment could come into play, as that does open the door for easy replacement of candidates on state ballots, for example: "The vacancy occurs because the nominee dies or is adjudicated insane or mentally incompetent, the vacancy may be filled "  So the fact that Biden is the incumbent President who could be subjected to Section 4 of the 25th Amendment makes this question unique because that opens the door to easy and late replacement of Biden as a candidate.

@JustMe There's still no 25th Amendment angle to this question, though. Even if you removed Biden (which is a big if), it still is up to the Democrats to decide who their nominee is. Now, if you want to ask if a sustained 25th amendment vote by Congress precludes a person from running for office again, that's fine. That's not, however, what this question is asking.

The question isn't about 25th amendment, it's about intramural political process within the Democratic Party - because the convention is still in the future and the nonimation hasn't taken place yet. If the conventional wisdom shifts to the position that candidate Biden is widely expected to lose, it changes everything.

The Democratic nominee will be selected during the Democratic convention in August. In that sense, President Biden is not the Democratic nominee yet, he is just the primary candidate with an overwhelming number of pledged delegates. As long as President Biden decides to run for the nomination, the Democratic Party rules expect the pledged delegates to stand by their pledge.
Convincing a majority of the pledged delegates to break their pledge is no politically feasible course of action, so one would have to convince President Biden to withdraw from the race. He cannot be removed from the candidacy, but he can remove himself if he wishes.

Might be worth adding some text for the scenario where Biden dies - surely the pledged delegates will break their pledge then (although they might vote for Harris, who would have to select another running mate).

@Allure, I don't think that scenario would be breaking the pledge. Did they ever have a precedent in living memory?

Within living memory? Don't think so, but there was the 1872 election where some electors pledged to the deceased (presidential) candidate voted for someone else.

"He cannot be removed. ..."  Invoking the 25th Amendment could do that, and IMO given Biden's performance last night that might very well happen.  Were Biden to be removed from the Presidency, what would that do to his ability to be a candidate?

@JustMe Nothing in the 25th Amendment addresses candidacy, and nothing in the candidacy processes of either party references previous 25th Amendment activity.

@JayMcEh So if Biden were removed under the 25th Amendment, would he even be eligible to run again?  No explicit reference to the 25th Amendment doesn't mean it has no impact on Biden's candidacy.

@JustMe, edited to clarify. I agree with Jay that the 25th does not appear to apply to candidates.

@JustMe Nothing in my library's overdue book policy explicitly refers to me running for President either, and that absence is exactly how we know it has no impact. There are very very few restrictions on being President, all Constitutional: 35 years old, natural born + resident for >14 years, haven't already served two terms, take the oath, and maybe some specific consequences for impeachment conviction and/or insurrection; that law is unsettled. Even fewer restrictions on running. Changes would require Democratic party to change their rules or a VERY fast Constitutional amendment.

@JayMcEh Oh, the 25th sure does apply to candidates and getting them replaced: "The vacancy occurs because the nominee dies or is adjudicated insane or mentally incompetent, the vacancy may be filled ..."  If Biden is found incompetent under the 25th Amendment, Nevada isn't the only state where he could be easily replaced.

@o.m. I found some states where the application of the 25th Amendment's Section 4 would allow for easy replacement of a candidate well after normal deadlines.  See the above comment for one citation.

@JustMe I disagree with your interpretation of that law, but this is already far outside the bounds for a comment thread. Ask a separate question on the Law SE if you'd like to know more.

And of course... the voters can just vote for Kennedy or Trump instead. Ultimately the people get to decide.

@JonathanReez And an alternate Democratic candidate could run a write-in campaign. But good luck getting any DNC funding....

re: "no politically feasible course of action" .... I don't think that will hold if one dials up the pressure - e.g. if Biden's polling falls another couple of points. Non gov such as the financial industry, central banks, or Israel lobby can and have exercised de facto votes of no-confidence over western governments and candidates in recent years (eg Sanders, Truss, Corbyn). The western legalistic system, rooted in common law, leaves room for pragmatic bending of the rules too. Finally, Biden's condition makes him vulnerable to sayng he doesn't want something, but handlers saying he misspoke

@PeteW, I see room for senior Democrats telling Biden to withdraw, and him listening to them. A different mechanism from engineering a revolt of the delegates. And I disagree with your characterization of the groups that would do it regarding Israel. Yes, they have a lobby. But that lobby could not push a more pro-Israel candidate than Biden on the Democrats.

@o.m. That's probably fair as far as the Biden known well by his sponsors and mentors since 1972. But the day is looming that Biden may space out for the last time, putting Kamala Harris in his position...
